# How do electron microscopes not get obstructed by atoms in the air?

Tags: atomic-physics, microscopy

How do different electron microscopes avoid just scanning the atoms between the probe and the surface of the object that is actually being scanned?

Comment: Do you mean an electron microscope? If so, the object is imaged in an evacuated chamber. They aren't anything like as wieldy and versatile as a light microscope: usually, the object takes a great deal of preparation.

Comment: In an STM (scanning tunneling microscope) there is no space for air. But in air, there will be adsorbates on the surface, generally almost as insulating as the vacuum.

Comment: You need to clarify whether you mean a [scanning electron microscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_electron_microscope) or a [scanning tunnelling microscope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scanning_tunneling_microscope) (or both). Also see the [environmental SEM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environmental_scanning_electron_microscope).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Electron microscopes, Transmission Electron Microscope (TEM) and Scanning Electron Microscope (SEM), are both operated under high ($10^{-6}-10^{-8}$ Torr) or ultra high vacuum ($<10^{-9}$ Torr) conditions. There are two reasons for this:

1. to keep the specimen clean
2. to avoid scattering of electrons by residual gas

So the answer to the question

> How do different electron microscopes avoid just scanning the atoms between the probe and the surface of the object

is that there is essentially no atoms between the probe (electron gun) and the surface of the object.